# Generate bookmarks within a newenvironment?

Tags: pdftex, environments, bookmarks

I'd like to create bookmarks dynamically, each time I use a custom heading (defined with `\newenvironment`) where the heading text becomes the bookmark name.

I'm using the bookmark package for `hyperref`, and I've considered using `\pdfbookmark` or `\section` within the environment declaration, but I need to be able to pass the environment contents into the command in order for the bookmark text to match the heading text.

I've also considered using `\begin{section}` and `\end{section}`, something like:

```
\newenvironment{heading}{\begin{section}}{\end{section}}
```

But I only get the first letter in the bookmark name, and it screws up my heading:

[image]

There are 7 headings, so my heading now begins with the number. How can you use unnumbered sections with `\begin{section}`
?

Also, only the first letter of my "Appendix" heading is taken and used for the bookmark, while the rest of the text is on the following line.

Here's a very simple example where headers appear on separate pages. When I compile it with pdflatex, I'd like bookmarks to point to each header's page.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=black,bookmarksopen=true]{hyperref} %bookmarks for pdf
\usepackage[open, openlevel=1]{bookmark}

\newenvironment{heading}{\fontsize{16}{19.2}\bfseries\selectfont\section*{}}{\vspace{3mm}}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{plain}


\begin{heading}First Heading\end{heading}

Text in the first section

\newpage

\begin{heading}Second Heading\end{heading}

Text in the second section

\end{document}
```

How can I configure bookmarks to be set for every use of my `heading` environment?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. `\begin{section}...\end{section}` is 'wrong', The `gobbling` of your section title occurs because `\begin{section}` sees `A` only and the rest is not treated as an argument delimited by `{}`. The special use case of this is a little bit unclear and we don't see any real code in action. If you really need this setup, try `\newenvironment{heading}[1]{\section{#1}}{}`, however

Comment: I also don't see the point in using an environment here at all, but this might be clarified in a compilable document, which is (still) missing (yet)

Comment: The full heading looks more like this: 
`\newenvironment{heading}{\fontsize{16}{19.2}\bfseries\selectfont\color{title}}{\vspace{3mm}}`
Where I need a heading to be formatted a particular way. The heading is referenced several places in the document as well as in a separate variables file, where the heading could be referenced multiple times. Because of this, I can't put the `\section` tags everywhere there is a header, instead I'd like to define the bookmarks in the `\newenvironment` declaration. 

I wouldn't doubt if there's a better approach to this.

Comment: That's not sufficient code. Please show a compilable document, not just fragments. You can add it to the post above, but not as a comment.

Comment: Most times there is a better approach ...

Comment: I added an example of a very simple document with heading environments on each page. I suppose using the `\section{}` environment might not be necessary, in my reading it seemed like the easiest way for the bookmark package to set new bookmarks. Also, what does your macro do for the section parameter: `\newenvironment{heading}[1]{\section{#1}}{}` ?

Comment: You don't need an `\end{...}` code for your environment, in my point of view

Comment: I'm still convinced that the environment is not necessary and an 'ordinary' macro will do as well.

Comment: I don't use bookmarks but I guess that `\newcommand\heading[1]{\section*{#1}\pdfbookmark{#1}{#1}` is close to what you want. The `bookmark` package disables `hyperref`s bookmarks so there's no point setting `bookmarksopen=true` for `hyperref`. The automatic section bookmarks are disabled because you are using `\section*`, which is why you need to set a `\pdfbookmark` manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use an environment, but if you insist, you can always consider using [`environ`](//ctan.org/pkg/environ):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage[bookmarksopen = true]{hyperref}

\newcommand{\headingfont}{\Large\bfseries}
\NewEnviron{heading}{%
  \par\addvspace{5mm}
  \noindent
  {\headingfont
    \raisebox{\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\pdfbookmark[1]{\BODY}{\BODY}}% Set bookmark
    \BODY}% Set heading
  \par\nobreak
  \addvspace{3mm}
  \noindent\ignorespacesafterend
}

\begin{document}

\begin{heading}
First Heading
\end{heading}
Text in the first section

\newpage

\begin{heading}
Second Heading
\end{heading}
Text in the second section

\end{document}
```

`\headingfont` can be adjusted to suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you! The environ package worked great. What I really needed was to be able to pass `\BODY` into the `\pdfbookmark` call. Works great!